# Mobile Push SDK version issue

Tags: mobilepush, mobilesdk, sdk

Our backend needs to send messages initiated by it (PUSH / EMAIL). A C# SDK documentation (https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-CSharp) was analyzed, which by the understanding is a wrapper of APIs documented in this link (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/routes.html). This SDK works on .net full framework up to 4.8, but it doesn't work on newer versions such as .net6. So, as there is an intention to evolve our aeroclass tool, this SDK will not be compatible. So I ask, is it possible to use only API calls (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/routes.html)?

Thanks!

Comment: yes you can simply make the api calls and not use the SDK wrapper

Comment: Is there any documentation to integrate mobilepush with the app without SDK? Thanks!!!

Comment: the fuelSDK and the push SDK are different things